# no member named 'snprintf' in the global namespace

Tags: c++, cmake, freebsd, poco-libraries

I'm trying to build Poco (as part of superbuild) on FreeBSD but getting

(building with -std=c++11)

```
[  0%] Building CXX object Foundation/CMakeFiles/Foundation.dir/src/AbstractObserver.cpp.o
In file included from /home/heather/A/SB/MITK-superbuild/ep/src/Poco/Foundation/src/AbstractObserver.cpp:17:
In file included from /home/heather/A/SB/MITK-superbuild/ep/src/Poco/Foundation/include/Poco/AbstractObserver.h:23:
In file included from /home/heather/A/SB/MITK-superbuild/ep/src/Poco/Foundation/include/Poco/Foundation.h:148:
In file included from /home/heather/A/SB/MITK-superbuild/ep/src/Poco/Foundation/include/Poco/Bugcheck.h:24:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/v1/string:437:
/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:143:9: error: no member named 'snprintf' in the global namespace
using ::snprintf;
      ~~^
/usr/include/c++/v1/cstdio:148:9: error: no member named 'vfscanf' in the global namespace; did you mean 'fscanf'?
using ::vfscanf;
```

How can I resolve it? I can't use poco from ports because it doesn't install `PocoConfig.cmake`

Comment: What compiler and version are you using? And what C++ standard library?

Comment: How is this question related to CMake? It is a pure C++ / Poco problem until you have good indicators that it is a CMake problem.

Comment: Post your linking from CMake, too

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch cc --version 
FreeBSD clang version 3.4.1 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot1-final 208032) 20140512

Comment: It seems, you are on FreeBSD 9.x. I guess, it has quite old libc++, so i'd just compile poco with gcc from ports.

Comment: Your C++ compiler/library combo is not compliant with C++11

Comment: Same problem with 
clang version 6.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_601/final 335540) (based on LLVM 6.0.1)
- which should be C++ 11, 14 and even 17 compatible